Why does EJS fetch return an error of asynchronous when I try to run it?
 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> 


Error: A listener indicated an asynchronous response by returning true, but the message channel closed before a response was received

There are these errors when i try to fetch with EJS source code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1><%=GroupBuyName[0][0]%></h1>
    <hr>
    <a href="/delete"><button id="delete"> Delete</button></a>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter a new name here" id="name">
    <input type="number" placeholder="Enter a value" id="quantity">
    <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>

    <ul>
        <% for(var i=1; i<GroupBuyName.length; i++) {%>
            <li><h1><%= GroupBuyName[i][0] + ': ' + GroupBuyName[i][1] %></h1></li>
        <% } %>
    </ul>   
    <script defer>
        const name=document.getElementById("name")
        const quantity=document.getElementById("quantity")
        const submit=document.getElementById("submit")
        submit.addEventListener("click",()=>{
            fetch('/add', {
                method: "POST",
                headers: { "Content-type": "application/json" },
                body: JSON.stringify({"name":name.value, "quantity": quantity.value, "id":window.location.pathname})
            })
            .then(()=>{
                console.log(name.value+quantity.value+window.location.pathname)
            })
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>

I know the error is in here because I've got a console.log on the receiving function
app.post('/add',(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.body.name)
    console.log(req.body.quantity)
    let temparray2=[];
    for (let i =0; i < activeGB.length; i++) {
        temparray2[i]=activeGB[i][0][0]
    }
    console.log(req.body.id.slice(1))
    let temp2=[req.body.name,Number(req.body.quantity)]
    activeGB[temparray2.indexOf(req.body.id.slice(1))].push(temp2);
    console.log(activeGB)
    res.send("data")
})

You can ignore everything else
Ive tried everything and i think that the problem lies in the fetch request

Maybe it is related to this? Try disabling all your browser extensions or run this code in an incognito window (assuming you don't run extensions there).
